# What is the source for saying tizku l'mitzvot?

Tags: sources-mekorot, language

It seems common these days to get the response "tizku l'mitzvot" for doing a mitzvah, usually a chesed for someone. Where did this response originate from and has anyone seen a discussion or source to use this response specifically instead of saying "thank you"?